# Index is not working with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1 collation but works with Latin1_General

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization, sql-server-2014, collation

UPDATE: The question was re-written, so some comments may be not relevant anymore.

After the change of the collation in the table we've got problems with the usage of the indexes. There appeared lot's of the scans. The default database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Now let's take a look to the example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('colltest') > 0 DROP TABLE CollTest;

CREATE TABLE dbo.CollTest
(
    cs       CHAR(8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL
  , ci       CHAR(8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
  , cs_latin CHAR(8) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT NULL
  , ci_latin CHAR(8) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ix_cs ON dbo.CollTest (cs);

CREATE INDEX ix_ci ON dbo.CollTest (ci);

CREATE INDEX ix_cs_latin ON dbo.CollTest (cs_latin);

CREATE INDEX ix_ci_latin ON dbo.CollTest (ci_latin);

WITH q (n) AS (SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 1)
   , q100 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM q a, q b)
   , q10000 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM q100 a, q100 b)
   , q100000 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM q a, q10000 b)
INSERT INTO dbo.CollTest
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) step
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) step
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) step
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) step
  FROM q100000;
```

And here are the explain plans for following queries:

```
SELECT cs FROM dbo.colltest WHERE cs = CAST('1000000' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT ci FROM dbo.colltest WHERE ci = CAST('1000000' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT cs_latin FROM dbo.colltest WHERE cs_latin = CAST('1000000' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT ci_latin FROM dbo.colltest WHERE ci_latin = CAST('1000000' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

[image]

So it shows that when COLLATION is SQL_* then it uses scans, when Latin* then it uses seeks. Why is that?

Comment: The SELECT has a small exclamation mark on it, what does that one say? Chances are you're having a implicit type conversion somewhere in your flow.

Comment: It is complaining to cast from integer to nvarchar(max). It is the same on both queries.

Comment: It's not shown in your first picture of the execution plan? A cast like that can cause it to not seek indexes but scanning them.

Comment: I see and understand that. But why is it relevant only for the 2nd query. This column is CHAR(8) in both tables, the difference is only in collations.

Comment: I'd _guess_ the cast to nvarchar(max) is a different collation to the index and therefore it's scanning. Try  something like `CAST( 42421164 AS nvarchar(max)) COLLATE XXXXXX` with the proper collation to the index. Also if the column is char(8) I'd cast to that and not to nvarchar(max). Especially if the exclamation point marker is a type conversion warning.

Comment: I can't change casting to NVARCHAR(MAX) as it is generated by EF code that is not under my control. Explicit COLLATE didn't help

Comment: I can pretty much recreate the issue and the plan change in one of my own databases, with an explicit collate on the cast to an "incorrect" collation. It also matches the issue description - but if it isn't working for you, then I don't have any other idea currently :/

Comment: I agree about the situation when the collation is incorrect so it needs to be implicitly casted. However in my case there is no collation conversion

Comment: The pictures of the plans don't provide needed details. Upload the actual execution plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the links to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've re-wrote the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [Comparing SQL collations to Windows collations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322112/comparing-sql-collations-to-windows-collations)

> For a Windows collation, a comparison of non-Unicode data is
>   implemented by **using the same algorithm** as Unicode data. ...
>   In a SQL collation, SQL Server defines **different comparison semantics
>   for non-Unicode data**.

`NVARCHAR` has a higher datatype precedence than `VARCHAR` so when you compare a `VARCHAR` column to an `NVARCHAR` the column needs to be implicitly cast.

**Example Data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
SQL_CollationVC   VARCHAR(1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
Win_CollationVC   VARCHAR(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
INDEX SQL_CollationVC(SQL_CollationVC),
INDEX Win_CollationVC(Win_CollationVC)
);

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(N'¹',N'¹'),
(N'½',N'½'),
(N'¾',N'¾'),
(N'0',N'0'),
(N'1',N'1');
```

The query

```
SELECT Win_CollationVC
FROM @T
WHERE Win_CollationVC = N'1'
```

Is able to perform a [dynamic seek](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx) and call `GetRangeThroughConvert` to convert the predicate into a seekable index range on the `varchar` index.

[image]

For the query

```
SELECT SQL_CollationVC
FROM @T
WHERE SQL_CollationVC = N'1'
```

You see a scan

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Note that this returns two results `¹` and `1`

Also note the results of this

```
SELECT SQL_CollationVC
FROM @T
ORDER BY SQL_CollationVC
```

The index on this column will be stored in the order returned from the above.

```
+-----------------+
| SQL_CollationVC |
+-----------------+
| ¹               |
| ½               |
| ¾               |
| 0               |
| 1               |
+-----------------+
```

`1` and `¹` aren't stored next to each other in the index so it isn't possible to convert the predicate `SQL_CollationVC = N'1'` into a simple seek on that index.